# Color java class

Tags: java, swing, colors

if I get color of text , I got :
java.awt.Color[r=234,g=152,b=28] which should correspond to orange
but when I perform the assertion : this is not working

```
assertEquals(Color.ORANGE.ToString(),myText.getColor());
```

expected :java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0] but was : java.awt.Color[r=234,g=152,b=28]

any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing String and Color objects. Correct assertion is

```
assertEquals(Color.ORANGE, myText.getColor());
```

Also the java.awt.Color.orange is `new Color(255, 200, 0);`.

Comment: I got : java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=0]> but was:<java.awt.Color[r=234,g=152,b=28]>

Comment: Then either your test is wrong, or your code is wrong. The fact the the color *looks* orange to your eye doesn't make it *equal* to the ORANGE color, which is defined very precisely as r=255,g=200,b=0.

Answer (score 1):

And anyway in java/awt/Color.java source ORANGE is defined as:

```
/**
 * The color orange.  In the default sRGB space.
 */
public final static Color orange    = new Color(255, 200, 0);

/**
 * The color orange.  In the default sRGB space.
 * @since 1.4
 */
public final static Color ORANGE = orange;
```